# App colors changing between design and simulator/device

Tags: ios, iphone, colors, rgb

in my screen app i have two views above each other, the top on is a UIview has a background color. the second on is an UImage has the same color of the top view.
The problem is although i took the UIView background color from the lllustrator, and took the UIImage from it too, they are quite different on the iOS simulator and device! 
the colors didn't match at all!
i really don't know what's the problem! 
any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have reputation enough to ask you first but I suppose you are setting the colors in Interface Builder, right? If so, then you have to set a Generic color like this:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah, for the first view i put the color profile as Generic RGB. but that doesn't work :(. 
and when i took the UIImage from the IIIestrator the color of the image changed in the simulator :|

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. You can check [this one](http://inaka.net/blog/2014/09/05/getting-the-right-colors-in-your-ios-app/) out.

Comment: yeah i try this tutorial too :( 
do you use it before?